# Array not being added to variable in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel-5, foreach

Ran into a weird problem and I'm pulling my hair out with it.

I've got this foreach loop

```
$rubrics = ReaderRubric::where('cycle_subpool_id', "=", $cycle_subpool_id)->get();
foreach ($rubrics as &$rubric) {
    $answers = ReaderRubricAnswer::where('rubric_id', "=", $rubric->rubric_id)->get();
    $rubric['answers'] = $answers;
}

unset($rubric);

Log::info($rubrics);
return $rubrics;
```

Log of `$rubrics`

```
[{"rubric_id":1,"reader_type":24,"document_type":"0","title":"test","question":"qweqwe","activity_type":null},{"rubric_id":2,"reader_type":21,"document_type":"0","title":"test","question":"testing","activity_type":null}]
```

Log of `$rubric['answer']` in loop

```
[{"answer_id":5,"rubric_id":2,"text":"asn 1","value":1},{"answer_id":6,"rubric_id":2,"text":"ans 2","value":2},{"answer_id":7,"rubric_id":2,"text":"ans 3","value":3}]
```

var_dump($rubrics);

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#74 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(Entrada\Modules\Admissions\Models\Entrada\ReaderRubric)#75 (26) {
      ["dateFormat":protected]=>
      string(1) "U"
      ["connection":protected]=>
      string(16) "entrada_database"
      ["table":protected]=>
      string(24) "admissions_reader_rubric"
      ["primaryKey":protected]=>
      string(9) "rubric_id"
      ["fillable":protected]=>
      array(5) {
        [0]=>
        string(11) "reader_type"
        [1]=>
        string(13) "document_type"
        [2]=>
        string(5) "title"
        [3]=>
        string(8) "question"
        [4]=>
        string(13) "activity_type"
      }
```

If I check the logs for `$rubrics` and `$rubric['answers']` it's exactly as it should be.

However, if I var dump `$rubrics`, none of them have the `$rubric['answers']` to them.

I know it's something simple, I've just been staring at it too long to see it now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you work with normal PHP arrays, there are a few ways to handle this. But since you have a `Collection` some array like behavior does not work. I think this little workaround should be enough to make the 'magic' getters/setters work:

```
foreach ($rubrics as $key => $rubric) {
  $answers = ReaderRubricAnswer::where('rubric_id', "=", $rubric->rubric_id)->get();
  $rubric['answers'] = $answers;
  $rubrics[$key] = $rubric;
  Log::info($rubrics[$key]['answers']);
 }
```

Comment: still nothing is being saved with the missing &, although that definitely was part of the problem

Comment: That's strange. I'll add a second approach to my answer, and you can check if it works that way. Still curious why this does not work.

Comment: ok, first time I see this error message "Indirect modification of overloaded element"

Comment: that means `$rubics` is not an array, but a traversable object. I'm surprised you don't get an error like 'iterators can't be used by reference'. Could you edit your question and add the output of `var_dump($rubics);` or the first few lines in case it's very long.

Comment: thanks. I added some code that should work for the object. Or you can always use Barmar's answer and store the result in an array.

Answer (score 0):

`$rubrics` is not an array, it's an object that implements the `Traversable` array, so you can iterate over it.

You can have your loop push the elements onto a real array.

```
$rubrics_array = [];
foreach ($rubrics as $rubric) {
    // do stuff to $rubric
    // ...
    $rubrics_array[] = $rubric;
}
```

From here on, use `$rubrics_array` instead of `$rubrics`.